# Where I'm wrong integrating $\int_{0}^{1} {\sqrt x} e^x dx$ by substitution?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$
\int_{0}^{1} {\sqrt x} e^x \, dx
$$

My attempt:

> I tried the substitution $$\ {\sqrt x} = t $$ and then I obtained $$ 2\int_{0}^{1} te^{\ t^2} \, dt$$ So I again substituted $$\ {\ t^2} = u $$ and eventually $$ 2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt u}{2{\sqrt u}}e^u \, du$$

Comment: I don't think you handled the $dx$ replacement correctly.

Comment: $d{\sqrt x}$ = $dt$ and $d{\sqrt x}$ = $(1/2\sqrt x)dx$. Then $dx$ = $2{\sqrt x} dt$; since ${\sqrt x}$ = $t$ follows $dx$ = $2t dt$. Is that wrong?

Comment: you will introduce a 2tdt, but you need to go through your entire substitution again carefully.  Write it all down for us.

Comment: I learned my mistake.. thanks both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{x}e^x=te^{t^2}$, we can see your first substitution forgot the $\frac{dx}{dt}=2t$ factor. (You correctly obtained this in your comment below @Randall's,) There wasn't a similar mistake when you tried to go from $t$ to $u$, so if you repeat the exercise you should get $\int_0^1\sqrt{u}e^udu$.

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution is wrong.

We have:

$\begin{align*}
 t
   &= \sqrt{x} \\
 d x
   &= 2 t \, d t \\
 \int_0^1 \sqrt{x} e^x \, d x
   &= \int_0^1 t e^{t^2} \, 2 t d t \\
   &= 2 \int_0^1 t^2 e^{t^2} \, d t \\
   &= 2 \left(
          \left. t \cdot \frac{e^{t^2}}{2} \right|_0^1
            - \int_0^1 \frac{e^{t^2}}{2} \, dt
        \right) \\
  &= e - \int_0^1 e^{t^2} \, d t
\end{align*}$

That last one (famously) has no elementary antiderivative.